# Odata V4 with DateTime

Tags: .net-core, odata

Hi I have problems when I use `ODate` for comparing my dates. When I do this next request:

https://localhost:44391/api/v1/Invoice/OData?$top=11&$skip=0&$filter=InvoiceDate lt 2014-10-30

I obtain the next error:

```json
{
    "StatusCode": 500,
    "Message": "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ConvertNode' to type 'Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ConstantNode'."
}
```

The dates that I have in my database is looked like at nexts:

```
2013-12-30 00:00:00.000
2013-12-30 00:00:00.000
2017-07-14 00:00:00.000
```

In my class `Startup` I had the next:

```csharp
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    List<string> listaControllers = GetControllers();
    foreach (string controller in listaControllers)
    {
        builder.EntitySet<BaseEntityDto>(controller);
    }
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}

private static List<string> GetControllers()
{
    Type parentType = typeof(ApiControllerBase<,,>);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    return assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType.Name == parentType.Name).Select(x => x.Name.Replace("Controller", "")).ToList<string>();
}
```

```csharp
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Filter().Count().OrderBy().MaxTop(null);
    routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
});
```

And in my entity `Invoice.cs` I had the next attribute:

```csharp
public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
```

And When I executed the last query in the Postman the controller (`Invoicecontroller.cs`) that is executed is the next:

```csharp
[HttpGet("OData")]
public async Task<PageResult<InvoiceDto>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<InvoiceDto> queryOptions)
{
    var options = new ODataQueryListOptions(queryOptions);
    var result = await InvoiceQueryService.GetAll(options.QueryListOptions);
    var count = await InvoiceQueryService.Count(options.QueryListOptions);
    return new PageResult<InvoiceDto>(result, null, count);
}
```

I don't know where the problem ocurred, and I need more information for solving the problem. Thanks to everyone for trying to solve this thing. I want to say that I use Views no Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Only put this in my entity solve my problem:

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
```

Thanks for all community for reading my question.